# Making sharp edges (vertices) of polygon curve

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I had drawn a polygon using UIBezierPath. I need to make its vertices curvy. How can I do that. I used [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(xPoint,yPoint)] method to draw lines. I tried using 
[path addCurveToPoint:self.nextPoint controlPoint1:self.controlPoint controlPoint2:self.controlPoint];
 But of no luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Polygon that needs to be made smooth]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your intent is. If you need your curve to pass through every vertex, you'd be better off using a different spline, such as Catmull-Rom splines. These have the useful property of passing through all of the curve's control points. Bézier curves do not have this property; instead the curve is bounded by the convex hull of the control points. You should also be aware that you will have to use an arbitrarily high-order spline to avoid self-intersection when your control points are very close to one another.

If you have well-behaved control points already in clockwise or counterclockwise order, the following code will evaluate and draw the closed Catmull-Rom spline connecting the points.

```
#define SMOOTHNESS 20

for(NSUInteger i = 0; i <= pointCount; ++i) {
    CGPoint p0 = points[(i + 0) % pointCount];
    CGPoint p1 = points[(i + 1) % pointCount];
    CGPoint p2 = points[(i + 2) % pointCount];
    CGPoint p3 = points[(i + 3) % pointCount];

    for(CGFloat t = 0; t <= 1; t += 1.0 / SMOOTHNESS) {
        CGFloat t2 = t*t, t3 = t * t * t;
        CGFloat x = 0.5 *((2 * p1.x) + (-p0.x + p2.x) * t + (2*p0.x - 5*p1.x + 4*p2.x - p3.x) * t2 + (-p0.x + 3*p1.x- 3*p2.x + p3.x) * t3);
        CGFloat y = 0.5 *((2 * p1.y) + (-p0.y + p2.y) * t + (2*p0.y - 5*p1.y + 4*p2.y - p3.y) * t2 + (-p0.y + 3*p1.y- 3*p2.y + p3.y) * t3);

        if(i == 0 && t == 0)
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);
        else
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, y);
    }
}

CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Resulting in:

[image: Polygon with smoothed vertices]